# Unable to build project with Stream Chat iOS SDK

Tags: ios, chat, getstream-io

I'm trying to use the new Stream iOS Chat SDK and am unable to get it to build after I install it via Cocoapods. The project was building with the other pods listed before we added `StreamChat`. I am using Xcode 10.2 (Does not work with 10.1), Swift 4.2, and Cocoapods version 1.7.4. We used the pod install command listed on Stream's website:

`pod install --repo-update`

Our Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'Project-iOS' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Project-iOS
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '4.3.0'
  pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper', '3.2.0'
  pod 'CropViewController'
  pod 'StreamChat'

  target 'Project-iOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Project-iOSUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
    end
  end
end
```

*Note that I tried this with and without the `post_install` bit at the end - but was having to manually change the pods to 4.2 since for many 5.0 isn't supported yet.

These are the errors I'm seeing when I try and build:

[image: Build Errors]

Edit: I also tried to get this running in a new blank project with just the `StreamChat` pod targeting iOS 11 (Basically just as the instructions on the site state for the ChatDemo) and ran into the same type of issues.

Comment: Hi Rachel, I tested your Podfile. I found a couple small issues that I can fix, but first of all you have to update Xcode to 10.2. Could you do that and tell me how it works for you?

Comment: @buh updating to 10.2 seemed to fix the dependent pod errors, but now I'm still seeing issues with StreamChat. I updated my question with the new 10.2 errors

Comment: I was able to temporarily bypass these issues by unlocking the pod files and correcting the code errors myself (not a real solution). However, once I got the project running I wasn't able to initialize the StreamChat Client. The documentation doesn't appear to be correct: https://getstream.io/tutorials/ios-chat/#stream-app. I'm not able to instantiate a user with an id and username. How can I set that initial user? Could you post updated initialization code here and/or update the docs?

Comment: Hi Rachel! I’m glad you can run your app. I’ll fix double optional condition for you. Tutorial generates a test user. Did you try it? Another way you can try set any name and id and for token set `.guest`. Let me know how it works.

Comment: This line from the tutorial doesn't compile because that constructor doesn't exist on the User object:
`Client.shared.set(user: User(id: "twilight-scene-8",
                                      name: "Twilight scene"),
                          token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidHdpbGlnaHQtc2NlbmUtOCJ9.REcUZ6wwhAb1kpMJsvjq0r64aaBZvVll1_bbVOOghH4")`

Comment: User has it: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-swift/blob/master/Sources/Model/User.swift#L53 Could you tell me the version of Stream Chat SDK you are using?

Comment: The StreamChat version downloaded with no version specification in the Podfile is 1.0.0. It looks like the StreamChat User object was conflicting with our local User object. I was able to get it to run after I prefixed it: `StreamChat.User`. It may be a good idea to give the Stream objects more Stream specific names to avoid overlaps

Comment: You can use this: `Client.shared.set(user: .init(id: "...", name: "..."), token: "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to your first question be sure to use Xcode 10.2 or later and Swift 5.

No need force pods to Swift 4.2. Try to remove these lines from your Podfile, then your project should compile without any errors:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There are still 3 errors related to force unwrapping non-optional variables when I remove that bit

Comment: Could you check in Pods project for StreamChat target that Swift version is 5?